# how to Show model data in the datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to show the Model data passed from one form to another form.

In first form I save the data to the database and also at the same time i get back the data to a model.
Now I want to send this model to a new form.
After sending it to a new form I want to display it in the Datagridview.
I did the rest of thing correct but now I cannot display it in the datagridview.
To be honest I dont know how to display a model in the data grid view.

```
company = GlobalConfig.Connections.CreateCompany(company);
            // MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(company.id));
            AddInformationForm form = new AddInformationForm(company);
            form.ShowDialog();
```

company is a model.

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Mohre { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNameEn { get; set; }
    public string CompanyNameAr { get; set; }
    public int CompanyLicense { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompanyLicenseExpiry { get; set; }
    public int MOI { get; set; }
    public DateTime MOIExpiry { get; set; }
    public ContactModel Contacts { get; set; }
    public SectorModel Sector { get; set; }
    public CompanyCategoryModel Category { get; set; }

    public CompanyModel()
    {

    }
}
```

how to display it in datagridview.

And Also when i just want to assign the values to the labels it gives me null exception reference

```
 public partial class AddInformationForm : Form
{
    private CompanyModel company = new CompanyModel();

    public AddInformationForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public AddInformationForm(CompanyModel cmp)
    {
        company = cmp;

    }

    private void AddInformationForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyNameLabel.Text = company.CompanyNameAr;
        SectorLabel.Text = company.Sector.Name;
        CategoryLabel.Text = company.Category.CategoryName;
        LicenseLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(company.CompanyLicense);
        MohreLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(company.Mohre);
        MOILabel.Text = Convert.ToString(company.MOI);
    }
}
```

the values are passed perfectly fine and also present it but still gives null exception.
what could be the issue here

Comment: Can you add your model class in the question for reference.

Comment: What is the structure of “company”? This is going to dictate how you add it to the grid.

Comment: `dataGridView.DataSource = collection_of_your_models;`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov tried to pass the model didnt work. it gives null exception.

Comment: Added the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like below:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<CompanyModel> { company };
```

or

```
var listCompanies = new List<CompanyModel> { company };

dataGridView1.DataSource = listCompanies.Select(c =>
new
{
    License = c.CompanyLicense,
    Name = c.CompanyNameAr,
    SectorName = c.Sector.Name//Todo:set your property
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Tried both methods, I am getting this Error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'".
althought the company has data in it, still gives this error.

Comment: Please check "Contacts,Sector,Category" fields in your "CompanyModel" instance(s).

Comment: they all have values in them.